# Windows 95/98 vs Windows 2000, XP+ Mouse Freeze

Tags: windows, mouse, interrupt, freeze, irq

I was thinking back to when I had Windows 95 installed on an old computer and how often times the mouse would show the busy icon and then completely freeze up. I remember not knowing if I should wait it out or if the system was locked up for good and I'd be forced to cut the power.

Back then, I didn't know much about computers to really troubleshoot but I'm now getting into Computer Science and programming which has me thinking about problems faced by developers in earlier years and how they addressed such problems.

That being said, I'm curious to know what the main factors were in causing the mouse to freeze like that in earlier versions of Windows and what has changed to make systems so much more stable now? When hardware devices need immediate attention, they can send IRQs, right? These were around in Windows 95/98, weren't they? So where did the main problem lie in regards to the mouse becoming non-responsive and how was it remedied?

Comment: it wasn't? I'm on win 7 and still get complete freezes, sometimes 2-3 times a day

Comment: That's odd, I've not experienced any issues like that since Win. 98 other than problems stemming from conflicting drivers or malicious software/viruses

Comment: This is caused by *pagefile thrashing*, the processor can't execute code because it got swapped out to disk.  Not having enough RAM and pagefile fragmentation were typical back then.  This question is not on topic here, use superuser.com

Comment: I noticed that freezes can be anticipated. I always get a "video driver has crashed and it recovered" message, then if I don't restart in 10-15 minutes, windows freezes and I need to turn off the pc from the power button